# UITableViewCell editing property seems to be reversed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm going a little crazy with this issue. I have a table view in which I want to show the table view cell delete editing control in all the cells EXCEPT the last one in a section. But instead I am getting the exact opposite, the delete control is showing in ONLY the last row. Can anyone tell me why?

In my view controller's viewDidLoad method I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO]
}
```

In my table view data source cellForRowAtIndexPath: method I have:

```
// All except for the last cell in the section are in editing mode
    if ([indexPath row] == ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]] - 1)) {
        [cell setEditing:NO animated:NO];         
    }
    else {
        [cell setEditing:YES animated:NO];
    }
```

I have also added

```
 - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `if` statements inside the `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` method and use `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for the last cell.

Comment: That works if I remove UITableViewCell setEditing:animated: calls. But I need to be able to show and hid the delete buttons without actually reloading the table view cell, and I wanted to do it with those call to UITableViewCell.

Comment: Could you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? It might have something to do with how you're creating your cell.